# nodejs server and nginx conflict

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx, node.js

I am running a nodejs application on a digital ocean droplet and I am trying to configure nginx so that it proxies the port the port that my application is running on,

This is what I have on my default file on sites-available

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /prwrite;
    index index.html index.htm app.js;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    server_name http://www.xxx.xxxxx.com;

    location / {

           proxy_pass http://www.xxx.xxxx.com:3000/;
           proxy_redirect off;
           proxy_set_header Host $host;
           proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

    }

    # Only for nginx-naxsi used with nginx-naxsi-ui : process denied requests
    #location /RequestDenied {
    #       proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    #}

    error_page 404 /404.html;
```

}

on changing `listen 80 default_server;`  to 3000, my node application fails to start at all

but using the configuration given, if i go to http://XXX.XXXXXX.com:3000 the application works fine

and loading http://xxx.xxxxxxx.com

gives me a whole lot of 404 not found errors on my page

How can i fix this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your application fails to start when both node.js and nginx are told to use port 3000 because only one application can bind to the port (considering they both are trying to bind to INADDR_ANY, i.e. 0.0.0.0).

You can solve this situation by adding the proxy location in nginx config, like `location /socket.io/ {` (or something more appropiate to your setup) pointing to your node.js running on port 3000 with `proxy_pass`.

Comment: Can i use a wildcard character for that purpose ? like location /*/ {

Comment: You surely can, but the way you are proposing will lead to the situation when node.js receives all of the requests and nginx serves none. Also note that when using wildcards and regexps you have to use a `~*` operator for example.